# laravel change validation default message from front side

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

Laravel change validation default message

- change validation message from front side
- read validation.php file and than write that file from front side

is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean `from front side`?

Comment: yes it's possible. But i think it's not a proper question here.

Comment: On Stackoverflow we expect you to do proper research before asking a question. right in documentation you have many options to customize validation messages https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation

Answer (score 0):

Use Validator class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

$rules = [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email,
];

$messages = [
    'name.required' => 'The :attribute is required',
    'email.required' => 'The :attribute is required',
    'email.email' => 'The :attribute is not valid',
];

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
} else {
  `enter code here`
}
```